# How do I "export" values from tableview function in swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, firebase, segue

I have the following function:

```
   public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt 
   indexPath: IndexPath)
   {
    let currentcell = telefonbog[indexPath.row]
    ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
    ref?.child("medarbejder").child(currentcell).observeSingleEvent(of: 
    .value, with: { (snapshot) in
        let value = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
        let Mail = (value?["Mail"] as? String)!
        let Mobil = (value?["Mobil"] as? String)!
//      self.test.text = Mail
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "kontakt", sender: self)
       })
    }
```

I see it the strings Mail and Mobil do not "export" out of this function.
My problem is that I need to use these two strings in the next window. but they are empty?

Comment: Correct, but can't get it to work.
I have tried all by now, know it might be very basic, but hopefully someone can help me.
Tried to populate another screen directly from function, but get a fail
Tried to return, but won't work.
kind of stuck by now

Comment: also tried to make class var of Mail_ and Mobil_, and that still work inside function, but they dont get updated outside function

Answer (score 0):

You're defining Mail and Mobil as *local* variables which will expire and become undefined once you leave the function (or closure in this case) - that's the normal way variables behave in Swift (or pretty much most languages).

If you want to keep the variables alive, they need to be defined outside the function as perhaps a class variable or pass them as a parameter to another function.

```
var mail = ""
var mobil = ""

   public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
   {
    let currentcell = telefonbog[indexPath.row]
    ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
    ref?.child("medarbejder").child(currentcell).observeSingleEvent(of: 
                             .value, with: { (snapshot) in
        let value = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
        self.mail = (value?["Mail"] as? String)!
        self.mobil = (value?["Mobil"] as? String)!
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "kontakt", sender: self)
       })
   }
```

or

```
public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
   {
    let currentcell = telefonbog[indexPath.row]
    ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
    ref?.child("medarbejder").child(currentcell).observeSingleEvent(of: 
                             .value, with: { (snapshot) in
        let value = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
        let mail = (value?["Mail"] as? String)!
        let mobil = (value?["Mobil"] as? String)!
        self.doSegue(theMail: mail, theMobile: mobile)
     })
    }    

func doSegue (theMail: String, theMobile: String) {
    //do something with mail and mobile var
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "kontakt", sender: self)
{
```

Comment: Hi Jay 
Thank you for taking your time to look at my problem.
actually I tried your no. 1 answer befor asking my question.
I dont know where i go wrong but even with a class variabel they reset once i leave the function.

what im trying to do is populate labels in "kontakt" with Mail and Mobil, if i try direct from func Tableview i get error, my code now looks like: (See my answer below)

Answer (score 0):

That was also my first guess. but the code below dosent, a breakpoint inside the func shows me that the Var is set correct, but a breakpoint just after exiting the the func shows it go right back to ""

```
var Mail = ""

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
{
    let currentcell = telefonbog[indexPath.row]
    ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
    ref?.child("medarbejder").child(currentcell).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
        let value = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
        self.Mail = (value?["Mail"] as? String)!
//      let Mobil = (value?["Mobil"] as? String)!
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "kontakt", sender: self)
    })
}
```

Comment: You kind of combined a few things that don't really need to be combined. If you want to set the var Mail_ then  you can do that within the closure, there's no reason to pass it to a function and then set it. that being said, if you have a class var, it will 'stick' once you leave a function that alters it. When referring to class level vars, you typically use self.var_name... so in this case it would be self.Mail_ = theMail. But again, there's no reason to pass it to a function and then assign it, just assign it within the closure.

Comment: Hi again
just tried to make a correction to my answer above
thanks again for taking your time to reply